# Using a PrintWriter and File Object to Write to an Output File

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I have a **JFileChooser** object used to get a data file from the user. What I need to do is create a **File** object and **PrintWriter** object so that I can write to a file named **"output.txt"**. The file should be written to the same directory from which the data file was retrieved from.

So far I have tried:

```
// Write to a text file`

File file = new File ("output.txt");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter (f);
```

This snippet of code creates the output file, but I need to it be written to the same directory from which the data file came from.

First thoughts were to call the .getPath() method (see below) on the JFileChooser object.

```
String fileDir = inputFile.getPath();
String fileName = "output.txt";
File f = new File (fileDir + "/" + fileName);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter (f);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inputFile.getPath()` will get you the file path. You need `inputFile.getParent()` which will get you the directory of the file.

```
String fileDir = inputFile.getParent(); 
String fileName = "output.txt";
File f = new File (fileDir,fileName);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter (f);
```

Comment: You can use `new File(fileDir, fileName)`, no need of concatenation. From [`File(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Misunderstood the API. Thanks for the clarification!