# How Can I Create A File In Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am working on a program that needs a lot of app data. I am trying to create a function that creates a file with the path/file name of the string path. Here's my code:

```
public static void CreateFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
    writer.close();

}
```

What did I do wrong? Shouldn't it create a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a PrintWriter and File Object to Write to an Output File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239053/using-a-printwriter-and-file-object-to-write-to-an-output-file)

Comment: What's your problem ? You are openning a `PrintWriter` and closing it right after... What do you expect that code to do ?

Comment: I'm used to basic where if you open a nonexistent file it automatically creates, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to create an empty file. For this, you can use `Files.createFile` or `File.createNewFile` (but it will require you to instantiate a `File`).

To create a non-empty file, just write something in it and it will be automatically created if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to this code :

```
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\FileW3.txt");// you can give path here

//or
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path name");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            pw.write("Combo stream and writer + using PrintWriter's write() methood/n");
            pw.println();
            pw.println("now using PrintWriter's println() methood");
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
```

Also

```
File f = new File("path and filename");
```

This wont create a file , the file object can be used as parameter in FileWriter or FileOutputStream to create and then write to that file.
File object is just abstract representation of file.

Comment: @STUDENTHiramAnderson the javadoc of the implemented interface `java.io. Flushable` says `Flushes this stream by writing any buffered output to the underlying stream.`

Comment: Thanks... I guess I was looking at the wrong documentation. :/

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) in the doucmentation - Create a file object then  call 'createNewFile()' method on the newly created object.